# como habilito e inhabilito las opciones de un menú

Tags: android

Quiero hacer algo  como este ejemplo pero en  android.

```
 else if (ace.Verificar() == true)
        {
            if (comboBox1.Text == "INVITADO")
            {
                Menu inicia = new Menu();
                inicia.Show();
                this.Hide();
                inicia.toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = " USUARIO : " + textBox1.Text + "******" + " CARGO : " + comboBox1.Text.ToString();
                inicia.iNSERTARALMACENToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                inicia.aCTUALIZARALMACÉNToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                inicia.eLIMINARALMACENToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;

            }
```

Esto es  la parte  que tengo en  android, quiero  inhablitar ciertas  opciones del menú desde el  login.

```
if (fila.moveToFirst() ==true)
            {
                String usua=fila.getString(0);
                String pass=fila.getString(1);
                if (User.equals(usua) && Pass.equals(pass) )
                {
                    Intent intentLogin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Menu.class);
                    startActivity(intentLogin);
                    et1.setText("");
                    et2.setText("");
                }

            }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías detallar más tu pregunta? ¿Es un  `NavigationDrawer`? ¿Quieres que dependiendo el usuario cargue ciertos items?

Comment: si es navigationDrawer, quiero que al loguear un usuario, si es  administrador podrá acceder  a  todas  las partes del menú, si es  invitado  tendrá  acceso  a  sólo  una parte del menú.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución rápida puede ser hacer uso de `putExtra` y `getExtras`, ya después comparas el *string* recibido y si es *x* persona muestras el menú, en caso que sea *y* persona ocultas algunos items del menú:

**Actividad Login**

```
//En esta variable guardas el usuario que obtengas, yo le he puesto admin directamente
String tipoUsuario= "admin";

Intent i = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
//Envías el usuario hacia la otra actividad
i.putExtra("usuarioIngresado", tipoUsuario);
startActivity(i);
```

**Actividad Menu**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
  //Recibes el string y lo guardas en tipoUsuario
  String tipoUsuario = intent.getExtras().getString("usuarioIngresado");
 //Comparas el valor recibido con la palabra admin, si son iguales que muestre, de lo contrario que esconda
  if(tipoUsuario.equals("admin"){
      mostrarItems();
  } else {
     esconderAlgunosItems();
  }

private void esconderAlgunosItems()
   {
     navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);// Colocas el id de tu NavigationView
     Menu miMenu= navigationView.getMenu();
     miMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_settings).setVisible(false);
     ...... //Colocas todos los items que deseas esconder
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente enviar datos dentro del bundle a la Activity que modificara su menú, esto se puede realizar de esta forma:

```
if (User.equals(usua) && Pass.equals(pass) )  {

   Intent i = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
   intent.putExtra("habilitaOpciones", true); //Habilita opciones.
   startActivity(i); 

}else{

   Intent i = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
   intent.putExtra("habilitaOpciones", false);  //Deshabilita opciones.
   startActivity(i); 

}
```

Para recibirlo, dentro de la clase Menu.java, se declara una variable y dentro de onCreate() se obtiene el valor:

```
private boolean habilitar;
...
...
boolean habilitar = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("habilitaOpciones");
```

Modificar el menú no es sencillo, el único método que puede acceder a modificar el menú es `onCreateOptionsMenu()` , el código para habilitar/deshabilitar opciones del menú debe estar dentro de este método:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // infla menú de su .xml
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);

    if (habilitar) { //Habilita
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_option1).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_option1).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_option1).setVisible(false);
    }else{ //Deshabilita.
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_option1).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_option1).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_option1).setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Pero **¿como modificamos el menú después de haberse construido?**, la respuesta es llamar el método:

[invalidateOptionsMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()) Declara que el menú de opciones ha cambiado, por lo que debe ser recreado. El método `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)` se llamará la próxima vez que necesite ser mostrado.

---

Por lo tanto dentro de `onCreate()` obtendrías el valor que determina habilitar/deshabilitar las opciones de menú y obligarías a un redibujado del menú con la nueva configuración:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
...
  boolean habilitar = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("habilitaOpciones");
  invalidateOptionsMenu();
...
...
}
```